# Calling dataflow job automatically on a finite interval

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gsutil

Is it possible to automatically call a dataflow job in the gap of every 10 minutes. Any insights how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is explained in the blog post [Scheduling Dataflow pipelines using App Engine Cron Service or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions)
.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same through gsutil? I'm thinking to write a shell scripting which will run infinitely in the gap of every 5 minutes. This script will give the call to my dataflow job. Is it a feasible option? Just a thought. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, you're probably looking for https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run